# Is there a program that edits audio files to have the same volume?

Tags: sound, banshee, volume-control

When listening to music in Banshee or any other player, I always have to up the volume for certain songs and turn it back down for others because they don't have the same replay gain.

- Is there an add-on which could normalise my songs in Banshee?
- Or is there a program which could do this to whole of my music library?

I'm currently running Ubuntu 12.04 in case that has any effect on the answers.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In `Edit > Preferences` Banshee has an option to enable ReplayGain correction. I think this is even turned on by default. Is it not working for you?

Comment: It works relatively well but for songs which have too much of a difference it doesn't do well enough for my liking.

Comment: Instead of using a bunch of different utilities for differing formats, you can just use sox.  There's an example in the man page I think...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I use a command line utility called **[mp3gain](http://mp3gain.sourceforge.net/)**, which is available in the repositories.

To use it, go into the directory where you store your music files, and then run this command:

```
find -name '*mp3' -exec mp3gain -r -k {} \;
```

It will go through every subdirectory, finding any file ending with `.mp3`, and normalize the gain so that they will also play back at a consistent volume.

Also note that `mp3gain` won't act on files that are already within the range you want, so the second time you run it and thereafter, it won't take as long as the first time. So you can just run this command as is every time you add new files, whether its just one new file, or a whole bunch.

If you happen to have `.ogg` files, there is a similar program called **vorbisgain**:

```
find -name '*ogg' -exec vorbisgain -r {} \;
```

There are options for how you normalize the gain for any one song in comparison to the rest of the music you have, but it's been so long since I've looked at them I can't really say much about it. I just know that I play my entire library as one huge randomized collection, and the above comand and its settings has worked for me for years.

If you happen to have `.flac` files, you can use **metaflac**:

```
find -name '*flac' -exec metaflac --add-replay-gain {} \;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Please note that compared to replaygain, which simply adds a meta-tag, mp3gain will *permanently* alter the data in your MP3s to normalize them; it's effect cannot be removed or reversed without technically affecting the quality of the MP3, although any difference may be imperceptible to most human ears.

Comment: @izx This is wrong. mp3gain is “lossless” as it uses a gain attribute in each frame of mp3 data. From `mp3gain(1)`: `Also, the changes mp3gain makes are completely lossless. There is no quality lost in the change because the  program  adjusts  the  mp3 file directly, without decoding and reencoding.`. So while it may be difficult to figure out the initial values, they're just modified by a constant offset, which is perfectly revertible.

Comment: Firstly thanks DaveMG for the answer, also, tied in with what @JonasWielicki has just said, can the constant offset be modified? And thirdly I'm guessing this won't work for flac files if I'm not mistaken? Any suggestions for that? I was partly asking the question hoping there was some software which did all file types .ogg, mp3 etc but this works already well enough for my liking, I'm just curious more than anything else at this point (I thought I'd add a comment here rather than create a new almost identical question for flac files)

Comment: Also I had tried the ReplayGain Correction in Banshee, it works reasonably well for most songs, however I did notice others where it didn't work as well.

Comment: @Oyibo I filed an edit request for the answer which contains what you have to do for flac files. Replace `*ogg` with `*flac` and `vorbisgain -r` with `metaflac --add-replay-gain`. mp3gain will calculate the offset in a way similar to what vorbisgain & co. do, so it should not be neccessary to do that by hand.

Comment: @Oyibo The Option in Banshee afaik _only_ activates support for reading RG-tags from files, it does not do the correction on the fly. So it won't work for files not having any RG tags (which may be why it doesn't work on some files for you).

Comment: @JonasWielicki I know I probably won't have to the offset by hand, I just want to know if it's possible to change it at some point as my laptop speakers are quite loud, also thanks for your help in completing an already good answer!

Comment: @Oyibo You would not want that, because the offset is scaled so that it plays along with other replaygain files. You would use your volume control for that.

Comment: Everything but the FLAC command works for me. I've edited the mismatched double quote in your example but I still get `*filename*.flac: ERROR: during analysis (decoding file)` for each file I try to process. Any tips?

Comment: Now (Ubuntu 18) Mp3Gain looks like unavailable, there is a replacement (bs1770gain) discussed in the following link, I just started to play with it, the results are surprisingly weird IMHO https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391446

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is an add-on for Banshee itself, but you can normalise volume across your collection. [On AVP](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/3772/674), I've found two ways to get it done:

- `sox`: install via `sudo apt-get install sox` or the Ubuntu Software Center. In a terminal, navigate to the directory where your music files reside using the `cd` command, then type `sox <input-file.mp3> <output-file.mp3> gain −n −3`. This will normalise the mp3 file's level to -3 dB relative to full scale deflection.
- `normalize-mp3`: this application is the way to go when you're handling multiple files. Install via `sudo apt-get install normalize-audio` or the Ubuntu Software Center. In a terminal, navigate to the directory where your music files reside using the `cd` command, then type `normalize-audio -b *.mp3` for artist albums, or `normalize-audio -m *.mp3` for mix albums.

Answer (score 1):

You can use audacity to normalize the volume of you whole music library.

> Audacity is a free, easy-to-use and multilingual
>   audio editor and recorder for Windows, Mac OS X, GNU/Linux and other
>   operating systems. You can use Audacity to:
>
> - Record live audio.
> - Convert tapes and records into digital recordings or CDs.
> - Edit Ogg Vorbis, MP3, WAV or AIFF sound files.
> - Cut, copy, splice or mix sounds together.
> - Change the speed or pitch of a recording.
> - And more! See the complete [list of features](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/about/features).
>
> One of these features, is ***Adjust volume with Compressor, Amplify,
>   Normalize and Fade In/Out effects.***<sup>1</sup>

**Note**:  Using audacity will affect the quality of your music.  But, if your music library is all high quality mp3, I mean 256 and 320 kbit/s, and the sampling frequency is 44.1 and 48 kHz, you probably will not notice a quality loss (drop).  Now audacity claims that they have significantly improved Normalize, but I think that this should be kept in mind before you try to normalize the sound.

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)</sup>

Comment: The problem with Audacity is that it will cause a quality loss (and make the volume change irreversible), because it has to decode and re-encode the MP3 file to be able to edit it...

Comment: I know, I used it on my media, of 320 kbit/s, and you can hardly notice any quality drop.  But you're right it does affect the quality.

Comment: agreed. Could you add a small note at the end in this regard? Thanks.